# Include and exlude in pandas (python)

Tags: python, pandas

The code count the rating of all the users (user_id) I want to count the ratings from only every user with ALLAN as sName .
The main code

```
grouped_data = ratings['rating'].groupby(ratings['movie_id'])
average_ratings = grouped_data.mean()
movie_count = ratings.movie_id.value_counts()
higher_than_50_votes = movie_count.index[movie_count > 50]
average_ratings.ix[higher_than_50_votes].sort_values(ascending=False).head(5)
```

A part of the first table.

```
 user_id     movie_id  rating    
    196        242        3       
    22        302         3       
    90        377         1       
    10         51         2      
    2         346         1       
    1         474         4       
    8         265         2       
    4         465         5       
    2         451         3      
    1         451         5
```

A part of the second table.

```
  user_id       Sname
    1|          AKERS
    2|          other
    3|          ALEXANDER
    4|          ALBERT  
    5|          ALBERT  
    6|          ANSEL   
    7|          ALLARD 
    8|          ALLAN 
    9|          ALLAN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways to do this:

1.Merge the Sname columns in the ratings dataframe, on "user_id"

```
ratings_with_names = ratings.merge(names, on='user_id')
```

This gives you something like:

```
    user_id     movie_id    rating  unix_timestamp  Sname
0   6           86          3       883603013       ANSEL
1   6           14          5       883599249       ANSEL
2   6           98          5       883600680       ANSEL
3   6           463         4       883601713       ANSEL
```

So now it's easy to only select the rows you need with [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
ratings_with_names[ratings_with_names.Sname == 'ALLAN']
```

2.Find the user_id that match a condition in the second dataframe, and use that to filter on the first dataframe:

```
ratings[ratings.user_id.isin(names.ix[names.Sname == 'ALLAN', 'user_id'])]
```